# Changing anchor point for popup without marker using Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, popup, anchor-point

Is it possible to change the position of the anchor point for the popup without using markers?

I was testing with this example. This code shows a popup, but I want to adjust the position of the anchor because it gets in front of a marker.

```
   var popup = L.popup()
    .setLatLng([testLat, testLng])
    .setContent("<div.... </div>")
    .openOn(map);
```

I already has markers and popups on the map and the position for those I get from a JSON-string. These popups opens when I click on a marker, but now I just want a simple popup to be visible when the map has loaded. I have tried to open one of the popup that I'm already have, but that does not seems to work. If that had worked, I didn't need to use a extra popup and change the anchor point for that popup because that is already done. This is a part of my code where I create the markers and bind them with popups.

Is there a way to open one of those popup instead?

```
// Add markers
for (i = 0; i < mapPos.length; i++) { 
marker = new L.marker([mapPos[i]["lat"],mapPos[i]["lng"]], {icon: numbers[1]}).addTo(map).bindPopup("<div>.... </div>");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to change the position of the anchor point for the popup without using markers?

Yes.

If you read the [API documentation for `L.Popup`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#popup), you should notice it [inherits options](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#popup-option) from [`L.DivOverlay`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#divoverlay). One of those options is [`offset`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#divoverlay-offset):

> `offset`
>
> type `Point`
>
> default      `Point(0, 7)`
>
> The offset of the popup position. Useful to control the anchor of the popup when opening it on some overlays.

Therefore, you can do something like:

```
var popup = L.popup({ offset: L.point(20, 30) })
  .setLatLng([testLat, testLng])
  .setContent("<div.... </div>")
  .openOn(map);
```